# align images horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I am creating an image slider and only 2 images are displaying at a time, there are two arrows on left and right to move the images, I have to place the image horizontally, but only two images are coming inline and other images are going down, I set overflow hidden to the image container, I can't set the width of the container as the number of image may very dynamically

so how can I set all the images horizontally (2 images on screen, others are hidden as the container property overflow:hidden)

the blue is the container and green boxes are the images.

[image]

code

```
        <div id="slidearea">
<div id="slider">

        <img alt="image" id="0" src="images/thum-1.jpg" style="margin-right: 5px; opacity: 0.5; border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">

        <img alt="image" id="1" src="images/thum-2.jpg" style="margin-right: 5px; opacity: 0.5;">

        <img alt="image" id="2" src="images/thum-3.jpg" style="margin-right: 5px; opacity: 0.5;">

        <img alt="image" id="3" src="images/thum-1.jpg" style="margin-right: 5px; opacity: 0.5;">

        <img alt="image" id="4" src="images/thum-2.jpg" style="margin-right: 5px; opacity: 0.5;">

        <img alt="image" id="5" src="images/thum-3.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;">
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: So you're saying that the first two images align correctly but the other ones are further down and don't align with the first two? Do they align with eachother? For example do images 3+ all align and images 1 and 2 align, but just not those two groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by using `white-space` & `inline-block` properties.

For example like this:

```
#container{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:300px;
    margin:30px auto;
    background:yellow;
}
#container #slider{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
img{
    opacity:0.5;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/*IE*/
    *zoom:1;/*IE*/
    background:red;
}
```

Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SNeVH/1/